# Clustering a sparse co-occurrence matrix

Tags: python, matrix, cluster-analysis, sparse-matrix

I have two N x N co-occurrence matrices (484x484 and 1060x1060) that I have to analyze. The matrices are symmetrical along the diagonal and contain lots of zero values. The non-zero values are integers.

I want to group together the positions that are non-zero. In other words, what I want to do is the algorithm [on this link](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/miserables/). When *order by cluster* is selected, the matrix gets re-arranged in rows and columns to group the non-zero values together.

Since I am using Python for this task, I looked into [SciPy Sparse Linear Algebra](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.linalg.html) library, but couldn't find what I am looking for.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a matrix `dist` with pairwise distances between objects, then you can find the order on which to rearrange the matrix by applying a clustering algorithm on this matrix (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html). For example it might be something like:

```
from sklearn import cluster
import numpy as np
model = cluster.AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=20,affinity="precomputed").fit(dist)
new_order = np.argsort(model.labels_)
ordered_dist = dist[new_order] # can be your original matrix instead of dist[]
ordered_dist = ordered_dist[:,new_order]
```

The order is given by the variable `model.labels_`, which has the number of the cluster to which each sample belongs. A few observations:

1. You have to find a clustering algorithm that accepts a distance matrix as input. [AgglomerativeClustering](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering.html) is such an algorithm (notice the `affinity="precomputed"` option to tell it that we are using pre-computed distances).
2. What you have seems to be a pairwise similarity matrix, in which case you need to transform it to a distance matrix (e.g. `dist=1 - data/data.max()`)
3. In the example I assumed 20 clusters, you may have to play with this variable a bit. Alternatively, you might try to find the best one-dimensional representation of your data (using e.g. [MDS](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.manifold.MDS.html)) to describe the optimal ordering of samples.

Answer (score 4):

Because your data is sparse, **treat it as a graph, not a matrix**.

Then try the various graph clustering methods. For example cliques are interesting on such data.

Note that not everything may cluster.

Comment: For converting a dataframe to a networkX graph, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57456069/how-to-convert-a-co-occurrence-matrix-to-networkx-graph